# How to denote the standard deviation with siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

I'm certain that I saw a command generating the following kind of output the last time I read through the `siunitx` manual:

```
\left( 12.3 \pm 0.4 \right) V
```

for a measured voltage of 12.3 V and a standard deviation of 0.4 V. I can't find it by searching the manual, though. Is this capability in `siunitx`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The code you are looking for is on page 43 of the `siunitx` manual (as of 2011/10/14):

> When a number has multiple parts (such as a separate uncertainty) then
>   the unit must apply to all parts of the number. How this is shown is
>   controlled using the multi-part-units options. The standard setting is
>   brackets, which will place the entire numerical part in brackets and
>   use a single unit symbol. Alternative options are repeat (print the
>   unit for each part of the number) and single (print only one unit
>   symbol: mathematically incorrect).

```
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}%
\SI{12.3(4)}{\kilo\gram} \\
\SI[multi-part-units = brackets]{12.3(4)}{\kilo\gram} \\
\SI[multi-part-units = repeat]{12.3(4)}{\kilo\gram} \\
\SI[multi-part-units = single]{12.3(4)}{\kilo\gram}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Seems like the siunitx in my texlive is too old, though. (2009/09/21 v1.3a)

Comment: @TimN Version 1.3a manual page 25 discusses the support available in that version. Basic functionality is the same but the option names are different (they were not as clear in v1.x).

Comment: @JosephWright: Thank you very much, straight from the source :) For reference to future readers: the relevant keys in 1.3a are `seperr` and `repeatunits=false`.

Comment: Can I set `[multi-part-units = single]` for the whole document? Or do I have to repeat it for every instance?

Comment: How can this be combined with scientific notation? e.g. `\SI{3.032e6(7.434e4)}{\meters\per\second}`?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to simply use `SI{12+-0.4}{V}` to generate the desired output after importing the package with `\usepackage[separate-uncertainty = true]{siunitx}`.

The manual can be found at [ctan](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), the parts about uncertainty formatting are on page 28 (as of September 2020).